# Xamarin - execute "OnAppearing()" code only when page loaded

Tags: xamarin

I have 3 pages, lets call them A, B and C.

Page A has a button, that loads page B, and page B has a button that loads page C.

page B has the override of `OnAppearing()`. I need this code to be executed when I come from page A, since page A passes the content that needs to be loaded. When I go back from page C to page B, I do NOT want the code to be executed again as it is unnecessary and takes a few seconds.

How can this be blocked?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a bool flag

```
private bool loaded = false;

protected override void OnAppearing()
{
  if (!loaded) 
  {
    loaded = true;
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: will this be reset when I come from page A?

Comment: only if you create a new instance of the PageA